# Setting the correct PATH into a MATLAB script to avoid including an executable in the work directory

Tags: matlab, path

I'm using a `dynare++` in `Matlab` in MacOS Ventura. This is a software that can be downloaded easily [here](https://www.dynare.org). When downloading this, you get a folder `Applications/Dynare`. The executable is located in `Applications/Dynare/5.3/dynare++/` , where the "5.3" stands simply for the version of `dynare++`. Now I create a folder in `Documents/MATLAB/dynare/5.3/` and I save the executable `dynare++`  in `Dynare/MATLAB/dynare/5.3/dynare++/`.

Once I've done it, I run the following in Matlab:

`addpath('~/Documents/MATLAB/dynare/5.3./dynare++')`

This can also be done manually in the "set path" option in Matlab. I've also done it and I get the same error.

Okay, so let's say that this `dynare++`  takes a `.mod` file and do stuff to get a `.mat` file. This should be done automatically by the program. I run the following:

`!dynare++ --per 15 --sim 3 --ss-tol 1e-10 MyModFile.mod`

and I get the following error:

`/bin/bash: dynare++: command not found`

When I run `!echo $PATH`  y get `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` , and I think the problem is here. So my idea is: I create a folder called `dpp/`  in my work directory and I copy-paste the `dynare++` executable there. I do it and then I run

`!dpp/dynare++ --per 15 --sim 3 --ss-tol 1e-19 MyModFile.mod`

Now it works.

My question is: It seems clear to me that MATLAB is messing the directories and for some reason if I include `dpp`  it understands that it's in my directory. If I don't include that, then it's lost. Hence, is there a way to help MATLAB to find itself where it is to not have to include that `dpp`  folder in each project that I create with `dynare++` ?

Thanks.

Everything is explained before.

Comment: Just give the full path to the executable when you run it. `! ~/Documents/MATLAB/dynare/5.3./dynare++  --per 15 --sim 3 --ss-tol 1e-10 MyModFile.mod`. MATLAB’s `addpath` is for M-files and MEX-files, it has nothing to do with where the shell will find an executable.

Comment: Don't ask me why but it doesn't work... But I didn't know that thing of addpath, thanks for that.

Comment: If you can run it like that from the terminal, you can run it like that from MATLAB. If not, copy-paste the error message into your post.

Comment: I run `!~/Documents/MATLAB/dynare/5.3./dynare++  --per 15 --sim 3 --ss-tol 1e-10 MyModFile.mod`and either `!~/Documents/MATLAB/dynare/5.3./dynare++/dynare++  --per 15 --sim 3 --ss-tol 1e-10 MyModFile.mod`, because the dynare executable is included in a folder named `dynare++`. In each case I get the same error: `/bin/bash: path: No such file or directory`.

Comment: This isn't really a MATLAB issue, you're running this command with `!` which is the same as calling `system( ____ )` in MATLAB or running it directly in the terminal instead of MATLAB. So using `addpath` within MATLAB won't impact this, you need all paths in the command (likely inlcuding MyModeFile.mod) to be given as either full paths or paths relative to the current _terminal_ path (not MATLAB path)